# Z-Value, Z-Near and Z-Far Within Kernel Function

Tags: metal

While loading texture within kernel function in Metal, is it possible to find the default z-value (if it exists at all) of the texture being sampled, the z-near and z-far values (likewise, if these values exist at all when the kernel is used instead of the normal pipeline using shaders) of the space in which the texture resides?

What I am trying to understand is:

When sampling a texture within kernel function, is it possible for us to change (or set) the z value of the texture before writing it? I have not been able to find this information along with the z-near and z-far values (is it even possible that we define these values manually when using the kernel function?) from the documentation.

Thanks.